# php mySQL error of syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not a newbie to PHP but I have encountered a [seemingly] simple problem which I cannot figure out how to resolve.

MySQL throws error that the syntax is wrong.

My Statement is this:

```
if($value){
        $query = "UPDATE ".$preuploads." SET words = '$words_amount' WHERE id= $sn_id";
        $db->sql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
    }
```

And then `$words_amount` is an integer, `$sn_id` is also an integer. They are double checked.

The statement when printed before execution is as follows:

```
UPDATE  SET uploads words = '250' WHERE id= 8081
// edited, with the name of table added since the problem primarily was 
// with the encapsulation and the name of table just was dropped in this question
// and not in the app
```

however words value (`'250'`) is tested with integer data-type as well, but no change occurs and the error lingers on.

And the error thrown is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET words = '250' WHERE id= 8081' at line 1
```

Comment: remove the string encapsulation on `$words_amount`?

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question, it is tested but nothing changes.

Comment: where are you updating your values. cannot see the table in your printed query? and try to run this query directly first in your phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Shail Paras You are right the table is not in the printed query but it actually exists and that was my mistake to miss it in the copy&Paste

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question (and `preuploads` is a table), then

```
$query = "UPDATE ".$preuploads." SET words = '$words_amount' WHERE id= $sn_id";
```

should be

```
$query = "UPDATE ".$preuploads." SET words = '".$words_amount."' WHERE id=".$sn_id;
```

Or, even better [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php),

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ? SET words=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param($preuploads, $words_amount, $snd_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

check your string `($words_amount)` has any single quotes `'` if it is then remove it by using this option on php `$words_amount=string_replace("'","/'",$your_string_variable);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found two errors:

First, not encapsulation of the data should occur, thus:

`$words_count` should be left as is, not to be encapsulated with `'`

And the table and fields name should be encapsulated with backtick

Answer (score 0):

I think your having problem with name of table. The syntax for update query is

```
UPDATE table_name SET words = '250' WHERE id= 8081
```